# ModelAndView in spring

Tags: java, spring

In spring when control return to view i have seen it return through,

```
return new ModelAndView("contact", "command", new Contact());
```

But i have seen a example where just a string name returns as below,

```java
 @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

        map.put("contact", new Contact());
        map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());

        return "contact";
    }
```

Is this also valid or a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is valid to return a String. It will be interpreted as the View name ([ref](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)):

> A String value which is interpreted as view name, with the model implicitly determined through command objects and ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods.

Is it a good practice ?

Let's say that's a matter of taste. (My point of view is that this *style* requires more knowledge about *implicit behavior* of Spring MVC and so I don't *like* it because it make the code more difficult to understand for someone not aware of all this *implicit behavior*, but it's really just personal preference...)

Answer (score 1):

This type of request mapping in the controller and passing models to the view page are the most exciting and useful aspects of new Spring MVC. Its perfectly okay to write the request mapping method like this. The interesting thing is `return new ModelAndView("contact", "command", new Contact());`, this type of return statement is being extinct day by day.

Cheers and happy coding.